# WebStorm / Rider - Cannot Debug Jest Tests - Unrecognized CLI Parameter: Unrecognized option "testTimeout"

Tags: debugging, jestjs, webstorm, rider

I'm working on a Vue.js 2.x project with Jest tests and, although I can run them fine, I can't debug them at all in Rider / WebStorm as I get the following error (paths abbreviated...)

```
/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/node --require /usr/share/rider/plugins/javascript-impl/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-stdin-fix.js /home/me/Development/Repositories/my-app/src/MyApp.Web/ClientApp/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js test:unit --runInBand --testTimeout=10000000 --colors --reporters /usr/share/rider/plugins/javascript-impl/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-reporter.js --verbose --testNamePattern=^VIEW: log-in shows a form where you can log in  --runTestsByPath /home/me/Development/Repositories/MyApp/src/MyApp.Web/ClientApp/tests/unit/views/log-in.spec.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:44527/c71be107-86f0-4e2f-ae31-2ebdd8c8892d
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
● Unrecognized CLI Parameter:

  Unrecognized option "testTimeout".

  CLI Options Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what to configure / tweak / change / fix to get this working. I can't just not send "testTimeout" as it's not under my control.

Is there something I should be doing with my `jest-config.json` file? It currently looks like this...

```json
{
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/(?!(core-js/modules/es6.array.filter|another-module|yet-another-module)/)"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/.*/__mocks__"
    ],
    "transform": {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$": "<rootDir>/img-test-transformer.js",
        "\\.(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/font-test-transformer.js",
        "\\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/media-test-transformer.js",
        "\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/style-mock.js",
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "testResultsProcessor": "./node_modules/jest-junit-reporter",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
        "json",
        "text-summary",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.{js,vue}",
        "!**/node_modules/**",
        "!**/dist/**"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT RECOMMENDED**
The workaround below does kind of work but it left me in a weird mess where one of my files was stuck with errors that just wouldn't go away. I suspect that not using the Vue CLI option means that the imports don't work properly. Something in Rider / WebStorm has now got convinced that it needs to run that particular test file that way and won't now be told otherwise - I was only able to get it to run properly by changing the file name.

Original suggestion follows...

*This isn't an ideal answer, as it needs to be set each time, but I managed to get the tests debugging by going to the run configuration for the test suite and under "Edit Configuration Settings" setting the "Jest package" setting to "jest" rather than "@vue/cli-service"
This then works for the given run configuration (Maybe....).
You can run a single test this way by right clicking the test run icon in the code window and doing the same.*

The downside to this approach is that it then seems to cause other errors - Namely "**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**" starts popping up everywhere.